# App camera crash

Tags: android, memory, crash, camera, android-camera

I use the next tutorial, in developer.android.com :
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
with API 2.1

- When I click in take a small picture, no problem
- When I click in take a small picture and after I click in take a big picture, no problem
- But, when I click directly in big picture, I take a picture and my app crash ...

In LogCat :

```
05-10 09:26:30.773: D/CameraSample(3407): failed to create directory
05-10 09:26:33.713: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3407): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-10 09:26:45.883: I/Parcours(3407): handleBigCameraPhoto
05-10 09:26:46.133: D/dalvikvm(3407): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 124K, 52% free 2628K/5379K, external 1685K/2133K, paused 207ms
05-10 09:26:46.143: E/dalvikvm-heap(3407): 31961088-byte external allocation too large for this process.
05-10 09:26:46.163: E/GraphicsJNI(3407): VM won't let us allocate 31961088 bytes
05-10 09:26:46.213: D/dalvikvm(3407): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2K, 52% free 2625K/5379K, external 1685K/2133K, paused 55ms
05-10 09:26:46.213: D/skia(3407): --- decoder->decode returned false
05-10 09:26:46.213: D/AndroidRuntime(3407): Shutting down VM
05-10 09:26:46.223: W/dalvikvm(3407): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:284)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at rdaquin.apps.takephoto.TakePhotoActivity.setPic(TakePhotoActivity.java:124)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at rdaquin.apps.takephoto.TakePhotoActivity.handleBigCameraPhoto(TakePhotoActivity.java:195)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at rdaquin.apps.takephoto.TakePhotoActivity.onActivityResult(TakePhotoActivity.java:281)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2549)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2595)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:121)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
05-10 09:26:46.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If have you need a code, ask me.

I do not understand why my application crashes, I feel that this is a memory problem but I do not know what to do.
So that when I do "take a small image" and "take a big picture" it works. But if I reload the application and that I "take a big picture" does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's pretty obvious from the stack trace, which says you ran out of memory because you tried to allocate 32MB on the heap. You can't do that. Not surprising since this happens when you take a big picture. You can't put it in memory. Write it to storage.

Comment: ok, but I have a question. Why I take a small picture and after I take a big picture, I have no problem. But, when I restart my app and I take a big picture alone, I have a memory problem ?

Comment: I have find a solution for my problem, I need to change bmOptions.inSampleSize in my example I put 5 and it's ok. Have you an idea for calculate a scaleFactor ?

Comment: That's asking the framework to scale the image down. Why not just take a smaller image to start with? Easier, faster.